# Challenge task to use function find() and set()

Tags: python, python-3.x

Use function find() and set()
takes an input string and Character to returns the Index of everytime that Character Appears

example :

```
String :  'abcabcabc' 
Character : 'c'
Character Appears Index :[2,5,8]
```

i need to accomplish this task without using any library

what i'm done

```
x = 'abcabcabc'
y='c'
z=[]

if y in x:
    z.append(x.find(y))

print(z)
```

but it's only print the first c index i need to code continue till the end of the string

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Good luck. When you've shown you can do this on your own (or at least ask a *question* detailing what you need), we'll be happy to welcome you to the industry and a useful member :-)

Comment: @MAK 
x = 'abcabcabc'
y='c'
z=[]

if y in x:
    z.append(x.find(y))

print(z)

Comment: @MisterMiyagi i edit my question  with my attempts

Comment: @paxdiablo i edit my question with my attempts

Answer (score 0):

Notice that the find method can take optional start and end parameters.

So you can call find(y, 10) to find an occurrence starting from index 10.

You can then run this inside a loop. Find the first occurrence starting from 0. Then look for the second occurrence by calling find(y, last_position), and so on until there are no more occurrences.